# I need to completely hide a JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

How do you completely hide a JQuery accordion?  Everything I can find when searching only explains how to collapse and expand the accordion.  Not how to make it disappear completely.

I want to completely hide the accordion...not just collapse it.

When I do this... $("#accordionName-" + tabId).accordion.hide();

I get this error...

Client Message: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion.hide is not a function

Comment: What do you mean "completely hide"? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ultimately did it (needed parentheses after accordion):

```js
$("#accordionName-" + tabId).accordion().hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since an accordion is a common JQuery element, you can use [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) function to completely hide a JQuery accordion.

Comment: When I do this...

 $("#accorionName-" + tabId).accordion.hide();

I get this error...

Client Message: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion.hide is not a function